# How do I install OpenBSD/ARM in qemu?

Tags: qemu, arm, openbsd

Could you share a specific command line & which file I need to download to make this work?

If you have a link to an OpenBSD/ARM image that is already installed (and a commandline to run it), that would work too.

Thanks!

Basically I want the ARM equivalent of https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/BSD#OpenBSD.

Answer (score 0):

Try `qemu-system-aarch64`. Check [QEMU's wiki](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/ARM#Guidelines_for_choosing_a_QEMU_machine) and `$ qemu-system-aarch64 -machine help` to figure out which machine you want to emulate. According to the wiki, `-machine virt` is a good default.

Comment: Thanks but what about the rest of the commandline arguments, and which files do I download?

Comment: Exactly what are you having trouble with? Please edit your question clearly stating this, as it is it's too vague.  Also note that the question itself seems to indicate you want to run OpenBSD as a guest but the wiki you point to is for using it as a host.

Comment: The section I linked refers to using OpenBSD as a guest. But point taken, will edit question now.